# NSPredicate in Swift3

Tags: nspredicate, swift3, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to change this:

```
return [self.allAttributes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, layoutAttributes.frame);
        }]];
```

into something that works in swift3. So far I have tried this:

```
  return self.allAttributes?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(block: { (layoutAttributes, bindings) -> Bool in
        return rect.intersects(layoutAttributes.frame)

    })) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
```

but of course I get `Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'frame'`

I have been searching the all day but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `allAttributes` is declared as `NSArray`.

Then anyway, you need some casting, so you can write something like this:

```
    return self.allAttributes?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(block: { (layoutAttributes, bindings) -> Bool in
        guard let layoutAttributes = layoutAttributes as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes else {
            print("some thing is wrong...")
            return false
        }
        return rect.intersects(layoutAttributes.frame)

    })) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
```

But if you contain only `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, why don't you declare it as Swift Array, `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]` ?

```
var allAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

//...

    return allAttributes.filter {rect.intersects($0.frame)}
```

You may need some fixes according to this change, but generally such fixes make your code more simple and readable.